# php echo statement fails to execute

Tags: php, html, mysql, crash, echo

I am trying display data from mysql database from within an echo statement, but it crashes the webpage. I have tried many different ways to do the same, but it still fails every time here is the code.

```
        <?php

        ...

        echo '<td>'. $row["NAME"] . '</td>' .'<td>'. $row["DESIGNER"] . '</td>' .'<td>

         <form method="post"> 
         <table>
         <tr>                                                
         <td><input type="radio" name="site" value="none"'. if ($row["SELLING_ON"]=="none" ){echo 'checked';} .'>no site</td> 
                                                              ^^^^^THIS IS THE OFFENDING LINE^^^^^
         </tr>  
         </table>
         </form></td>

         <td>'. $row["MSRP_USED"] . '</td>' .'<td>'. $row["ORIGINAL_PRICE"] . '</td>' ;


         ...


         ?>
```

Look at the line where I say "this is the offending line." As soon as I remove that line, everything works fine as it should.

Comment: you cannot concatenate the if statement like that, use a ternary operator instead. `(condition) ? true : false` like so

Comment: You should be getting a syntax error on that line.

Comment: @Barmar That's the thing. I am not getting error. am I suppose to get an error on the browser?

Comment: you can show the error by adding `ini_set("display_error", "1");` at the first line of your PHP script.

Comment: You should be getting a syntax error on the server, you'll probably get a blank screen in the browser.

Comment: @Raptor I added that line in my php file and still the same. All I see is blank screen. There is nothing on it.

Comment: @Raptor okay. Where in the server can I find it?

Comment: But do you guys see anything wrong with the syntax itself for that line?

Comment: Your script contains syntax error. You should check PHP error log instead. If you are unsure about the syntax, please learn from the PHP basics. Besides, try not to use nested HTML tables, which will impact performance. Consider using DIV instead.

Comment: In general, I find the [alternative syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) a better choice when mixing PHP with HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separate the if statement from the string

```
echo '<td>'. $row["NAME"] . '</td>' .'<td>'. $row["DESIGNER"] . '</td>' .'<td>

     <form method="post"> 
     <table>
     <tr>                                                
     <td><input type="radio" name="site" value="none"';
if ($row["SELLING_ON"]=="none" ){
echo 'checked';
}
echo '>no site</td></tr>  
     </table>
     </form></td>

     <td>'. $row["MSRP_USED"] . '</td>' .'<td>'. $row["ORIGINAL_PRICE"] . '</td>' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
<td> <?php echo $row["NAME"]?> </td>
<td> <?php echo $row["DESIGNER"]?> </td>
<td>
  <form method="post"> 
   <table>
    <tr>                                                
     <td>
      <input type="radio" name="site" value="none" <?php if($row["SELLING_ON"]=="none" ){echo 'checked';}?> >no site
     </td>
    </tr>  
   </table>
  </form>
 </td>
 <td> <?php echo $row["MSRP_USED"]?> </td>
 <td> <?php echo $row["ORIGINAL_PRICE"]?> </td>
```